# Função do php não retorna a imagem

Tags: php, funções, imagem, return, img

Bom dia, a função não está retornando a img.
*Apenas o nome da img vem do banco de dados.
*Se eu uso o código sem função colocando direto no html funciona.
*Ele retorna os outros elementos como: tipo, nome ,região etc.
*O caminho estar certo. Fiz o teste colocado um nome de uma img na mão(Da mesma pasta onde estou armazenado).

Erro:

> Notice : Undefined variable: events in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Smart-look\src\componentes\funcoes.php on line 5
>
> Notice : Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Smart-look\src\componentes\funcoes.php on line 5
>
> Notice : Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Smart-look\src\componentes\funcoes.php

```
    <?php
function renderizar_box_denuncias($events1){
    $i = 0;
    foreach($events1 as $events1s){
        
        echo('
            <div class="min_box">
                <div class="box_img">
                    <img  src="./../views/img_denu/'.$events[$i][5].' " alt="Logo">
                </div>
            
                <div class="for">
                    
                    <div class="container_elements"> 
                        <label for="">Tipo:</label>
                        <p>'.$events1[$i][2].'</p>
                    </div>
                

                    <div class="container_elements"> 
                        <label for="">Região:</label>
                        <p>'.$events1[$i][1].'</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container_elements"> 
                        <label for="">CEP da rua:</label>
                        <p>'.$events1[$i][3].'</p>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="container_elements"> 
                        <label for="">Data:</label>
                        <p>'.$events1[$i][6].'</p>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="container_elements"> 
                        <label for="">Comentarios:</label>
                        <p>'.$events1[$i][4].'</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>'
        );
    $i ++;
    }
   
    if($i<=0){
        echo('<p  style=color:black;>
            Você não tem denúncias canceladas;</p>'
        );

    }
    return;
}
```

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['nome']){
    header("location: ./login/sair.php");
}
require_once('./../evento/action/conexao.php');
require_once("./../componentes/funcoes.php");
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->conectar();
$cpf=$_SESSION['cpf'];
$sql1 = "SELECT * from denuncias where validacao='e'AND cpf='".$cpf."' ;";

$sql_pre1 = $db->prepare($sql1);
$sql_pre1 -> execute();
$events1 = $sql_pre1->fetchAll();


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="./css/my_canceled.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <link href="./../componentes/componentes.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <?php include_once("./../componentes/navbar.php")?>
    <div class="main">
        <?php include_once("./../componentes/sub_navbar.php")?>
        <div class="page">

        <?php renderizar_box_denuncias($events1);?>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
        
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Na linha onde esta pegando o nome da imagem, altere a variavel de $events para $events1

Altere de

```
<img  src="./../views/img_denu/'.$events[$i][5].' " alt="Logo">
```

para

```
<img  src="./../views/img_denu/'.$events1[$i][5].' " alt="Logo">
```

Veja se isso resolve o seu problema.

Comment: Estou me sentindo idiota sem ter percebido isso kkkk, vlw